# How to read multiple tab space character from text area by jQuery and convert into space?

Tags: jquery, html

When I am copying the bellow given data from excel sheet and copy into text area, after first column it is not considering like space but tab space.

```
123 sn60d   809
123 sn60d   809
543 gf645d  32
```

when reading these value from text area it is like bellow given.

```
123sn60d809 123sn60d809 543gf645d32
```

I want space between column.

Comment: how r you copying data ?

Comment: Copying from excel sheet using right click ..

Comment: On copying data from Excel sheet cells values are separated by tab. You can paste data in textpad, which will be tab separated. Then replace 'tab' by 'space' using F8.

Comment: @user2947 My requirement is copying data from excel sheet and pest it into browser text area, from there I have need to perform some operation.

Comment: unresolved Tab space issue ...

Answer (score 0):

The line break is actually `\n\r`, just try replacing to `<br />` or whatever.

```
var text = $("#textarea").val();
text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

Comment: I tried but it is not resolving. you get result liek .....
123 sn60d 809<br />123 sn60d 809<br />
but I want like .....
123<br />sn60d<br/>809 .....

Comment: @Ravi where are you trying to print the text?

Comment: I am copy from excel and pesting into text area and trying to get those value into jquery....to perform some operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Excel File->Save As... and tell it to save the data as plain text.  Then there aren't any tabs.  Or you can save it as a CSV file and tell it to not use tabs.

HOWEVER!  You need some way to tell what is what.  Using tabs is a great way to tell which column you are currently on.  In Javascript all you then have to do is to iterate over the entire list and use the split() function to break up the line like so:

```
 var a = excel.split("<TAB>");
```

This would make a SINGLE line become:

```
    var a = "123 sn60d 809";
    var b = a.split("<TAB>");

//   So b[0] = "123"
//      b[1] = "sn60d"
//      b[2] = "809"

So if you had multiple lines like in your example:

    var a = "123 sn60d 809\n";
     a = a + "123 sn60d 809\n";
     a = a + "543 gf645d 32\n";

    var b = a.split("\n");
    for( var i=0; i<b.length; i++ ){
        var c = b[i].split("<TAB>");
       }
```

So variable "a" contains all of the lines, variable "b" then contains all of the lines split apart by the newline character, and variable "c" then contains each of the tab separated varlues.

Once you have everything separated out you can put it back together however you want to do so.  Just use the join() command.  So...

```
   var d = c.join(' ' );
```

The above puts a space between each of the values instead of a tab.  Then you can just put it in to your textarea or where ever.  I hope this helps.

PS: You can also just use the replace command to replace the tabs with spaces or something else too.  :-)

Comment: Thanks
I tried but b[i].split("<TAB>") is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my question implementing NICEDIT RTF.
It generate internal table and from that table we can get all value with white space or with complete html table. http://www.nicedit.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just replace tab character with space:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('textarea');
textArea.value = textArea.value.replace(/\t/g, ' ');
```

Comment: I was unable to get tab space value in javascript. If you are able to get it please let me share your running code. I will be thankful to you  :)

Comment: `var textArea = document.getElementById('textarea');
for (var i = 0; i < textArea.value.length; i++) {
    if (textArea.value.charCodeAt(i) == 9) {
        //do something
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Regularly paste text from excel sheet into a textarea tag are separated by a tab space character `\t` (char code 9) between cells and separated by a new line character `\n` (char code 10) between rows. If you wanna get those characters within JavaScript then you can use `string.charAt(charIndex)`, or if you wanna get the character code then you can use `string.charCodeAt(charIndex)`.
Please try below snippet:

```js
var textInput = document.getElementById('text-input');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
textInput.value = 'Please paste here some text from Excel sheet...';
textInput.selectionStart = 0;
textInput.selectionEnd = textInput.value.length;
textInput.focus();

function process() {
 var strSrc = textInput.value.replace(/\t/g, ' [\\t] ');
 strSrc = strSrc.replace(/\n/g, ' [\\n]\n');
 strSrc = strSrc.replace(/\n$/, '');
 var custom1 = '[' + textInput.value.replace(/\t/g, '] [');
 custom1 = custom1.replace(/\n/g, ']\n[');
 custom1 = custom1.replace(/\n\[$/, '');
 custom1 = custom1.replace(/([^\]])$/, '$1]');
 var custom2 = custom1.replace(/\] \[/g, ' ');
 var custom3 = custom1.replace(/\] \[/g, '');
 result.innerHTML =
  'Your source text: \n' +
  strSrc + '\n' +
  '\n' +
  'Custom format 1: \n' +
  custom1 + '\n' +
  '\n' +
  'Custom format 2: \n' +
  custom2 + '\n' +
  '\n' +
  'Custom format 3: \n' +
  custom3;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text-input" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" cols="80" rows="12"></textarea>
<p><button onclick="process();">Process...</button></p>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for your grateful reply. Now It will help someone else.
I tried it is working properly. You did smart job..